# confirmation email not sent

Tags: email

I am working in magento 1.9.2.2.When a new customer registers, the message is displayed saying that the confirmation mail is sent but confirmation mail is not sent.Also I have already set system->configuration->customer->customer configuration->Require emails confirmation=yes.Should anything be done additionally.Kindly anyone guide me.

Comment: any other e-mails are sent?

Comment: No. just now I checked.

Comment: this means magento is not the problem. Your mail server might be the problem.

Comment: also check if the e-mail communication is not disabled from system->configuration->email settings

Comment: yea the 'require emails confirmation' option is set to yes

Comment: @Ramya as Marius said check whether the mail server is configured or not and even check whether cron jobs are working or not. please check with your server team.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a new magento installation, and you notice that the join process takes a very long time to complete, your sendmail is probably the source.Some new servers dont have sendmail setup properly and you need to adjust a few things.For slow email from the app, edit 3 files.
1)  /etc/resolv.conf, add search whateveryourdomainnameis.com in before the nameservers.

```
[root@Web1 etc]# cat /etc/resolv.conf
search whateveryourdomain.com
nameserver 123.123.123.12
nameserver 123.123.123.12
```

2) /etc/mail/sendmail.cf Uncomment the line 0 HostsFile=/etc/hosts

```
# hosts file (normally /etc/hosts)
O HostsFile=/etc/hosts
```

3) /etc/hosts add www.whateveryourdomainnameis.com and whateveryourdomainnameis.com to the IP address for this server.

```
127.0.0.1 localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4
::1 localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6
10.183.131.193 Web1
22.222.344.42 Web1
127.0.0.1 www.whateveryourdomainnameis.com whateveryourdomainnameis.com
```

4) Also I added sendmail to the chkconfig to make sure it restarts if the server restarts

```
[root@Web1 etc]# chkconfig sendmail on
```